# Calabash-iOS Unable to find AutomationInstrument.bundle (RuntimeError)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, calabash

My Xcode is installed in the following path

```
 xcode-select -print-path = /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools



 Mohammeds-MacBook-Pro:story yaseen$ cucumber
```

Gives the following error

```
   Feature: Running a test
  As an iOS developer
 I want to have a sample feature file
 So I can begin testing quickly

 Scenario: Example steps                            # features/my_first.feature:6
 Unable to find AutomationInstrument.bundle (RuntimeError)
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/run_loop-0.0.22/lib/run_loop/core.rb:319:in        `default_tracetemplate'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/run_loop-0.0.22/lib/run_loop/core.rb:309:in `automation_template'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/run_loop-0.0.22/lib/run_loop/core.rb:295:in `instruments_command'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/run_loop-0.0.22/lib/run_loop/core.rb:135:in `run_with_options'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/run_loop-0.0.22/lib/run_loop/core.rb:362:in `run'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.9.162/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:222:in `block in new_run_loop'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.9.162/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:220:in `times'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.9.162/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:220:in `new_run_loop'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.9.162/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:159:in `relaunch'
    /Users/yaseen/Desktop/iOS-Github/Story/features/support/01_launch.rb:29:in `Before'
    Given I am on the Welcome Screen                 #     features/step_definitions/my_first_steps.rb:1
  Then I swipe left                                # calabash-cucumber-  0.9.162/features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb:237
  And I wait until I don't see "Please swipe left" # calabash-cucumber-0.9.162/features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb:168
  And take picture                                 # calabash-cucumber-0.9.162/features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb:232

  Failing Scenarios:
  cucumber features/my_first.feature:6 # Scenario: Example steps

  1 scenario (1 failed)  
  4 steps (4 skipped)
 0m3.401s
```

If you suggest me to move my **Xcode5** into **Applications** Directory How can i do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got a solution

If your Xcode path is not=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

change it in terminal

```
   sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```